# Antenna selection problem

Tags: pcb-antenna

I need a pcb gps and a gprs antenna. But their size is very important. I'm thinking about fitting those into a leather dog leash. What can I use for this purpose?

Comment: a mobile GPS tracker for animals? shop with these keywords

Comment: What I need is not the tracker but which antennas I would have to use if I wanted to build one :)

Comment: antennae are always directional, so rubber ducky or patch antenna both have disadvantages, but either may be used as long as pointing in correct direction... up for patch, it's impossible to control, and often not critical unless in fringe areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know nothing about GPS antennae,  start here

https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/GPS-Antenna_AppNote_%28GPS-X-08014%29.pdf?utm_source=en%2Fimages%2Fdownloads%2FProduct_Docs%2FGPS_Antennas_ApplicationNote%28GPS-X-08014%29.pdf

The most popular for pets seems to be the GeoHelix type printed helix copper foil on low loss tangent substrate. .e.g. special FPC substrate

Comment: How about the antennas inside cell phones which are used for GPS and GPRS? I saw these https://www.aliexpress.com/cheap/cheap-antenna-sticker.html as cheap antennas. Would these be usefuld for me? I'm thinking about to use the antennas with This one http://www.electrodragon.com/product/gsm-gprs-gps-module-a7-breakout/ instead of using two fat antennas.

Comment: orientation and loss of signal must be tested on subject. a simple 1/4wave piece of wire is perfect in the right directions (radial) but not close to body. and that's almost  free, but hard to control on a dog.

Comment: But how these stuff are done into the cellphones easily? Their sizes are not so big. You know a collar is something like a belt for dog's neck. I was believing that the antennas could be 2 different cables housed into that belt. :( What should I do?

Comment: without test experience or equipment... follow what you know works